# Need help with getting list of items in Page factory, c#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, c#, page-objects

I'm new to Page factory model - I need number of elements in list, I'm trying in the following way:

```
**[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id='ABC']/div")]
public List<IWebElement> allElements;
Console.Write("Number of Elements: " +allElements.Count);**
```

When I run my test I'm getting:

> ERROR system.argumentexception: object of type
> 'castle.Proxies.IwrapsElementProxy_1' cannot be converted to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1 [OpenQA.Selenim.IWebElemen]'

Not sure what is going wrong here.

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am only on my phone right now so can't try out any tests for this, but the problem here looks like the findsby attribute for the page object factory in Selenium is expecting to locate and return only a single instance of IWebElement rather than the collection you are trying to have it locate.

I'm not sure if there is an additional attribute that tells Web Driver that the locator is for an IEnumerable of elements instead, but that's where I'd start looking.